# Print different value each time key is called

Tags: perl, hash

I need some help with Perl.

I have a list of IDs & corresponding values in a file. Each ID acts as a key in a hash of hashes so there are multiple values for each key. I'm trying to open a second file & assign a different value each time the key is encountered. Here is what I have so far:

This code takes the input file & builds the hash of hashes. $prot is the key & $dir is the value. Each key has multiple values.

```
open (IN, "file_name");
while (<IN>)
{
 ($prot, $dir) = split;
 push (@{$dir{$prot}}, $dir );
}
```

In the second part of the code, I would like to read each line of the file & assign a different value using the first column in the line as the key. Each key will appear multiple times in the second file & for each instance I would like it to print a different value.

```
open (FH, "results_file");
while (<FH>)
{
chomp;
@a=split;
$prot=$a[1];
foreach  (values %dir)
{print "$a[1]"."\t"."@{$dir{$prot}}"."\n";}
}
```

Right now the way the code is written it prints all the values for each key when it encounters the key.

Thanks so much for any help that can be offered!

Edit:

The first input file is something along the lines of

```
BC_123456     dir_6789
BC_456789     dir_3456
BC_234689     dir_1298
BC_123456     dir_3987
BC_876432     dir_7642
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the input file? If you use Data::Dumper; print Dumper ($dir); at the end of your first example, does the datastructure look like you expect?

Comment: I added a sample of the first input file. After I put it into the hash of arrays, the data structure looks as I expect.

Comment: I'm struggling with how you want to "assign a different value". You say "first column", but you use the second (note the indexing for the array from split is zero-based). Do you want to assign a different value to your array of hashes? or do you just want to temporarily assign a value for printing purposes?

Answer (score 0):

> Each ID acts as a key in a hash of hashes

You actually have a hash of arrays there.

Assuming you want to print the first value for the first instance, second for the second instance, and so on, you can just shift off the values for each key you encounter:

```
open (FH, "results_file");
while (<FH>)
{
chomp;
@a=split;
$prot=$a[1];
    foreach  (values %dir) {
        my $val = shift @{$dir{$prot}};
        print "$a[1]\t$val\n";
    }
}
```

This will remove one value from the HoA entry, assuming you don't need to use that array afterwards.

Comment: First off, thank you for correcting me with the hash of arrays versus the hash of hashes! :-) Secondly, I tried your answer & it keeps telling me $val is uninitialized when I try to print it.

Comment: @sapo42 If $val is coming back uninitialized then either (1) the array at that hash position is already empty, or (2) you had pushed undef values into the array (unlikely if your sample data is correct). What do you expect to happen after you have already printed all the values from the first input file?

Answer (score 0):

I think this gets your code working. There are some best practices to note:

- You should always run under strict & warnings.

  - `use strict;`
  - `use warnings;`
- I recommend the three argument version of `open()`, with an error check (`or die "message $!";`), and a lexical variable to store the filehandle.

  - See:
  - `perldoc -f open`
  - `perldoc perlopentut`
- Close your files when done using them.
- Variables should be introduced (declared) with `my` unless you have a good reason to use something else.

I also made a couple changes that while I recommend, they aren't necessary.

- Removed variable `@a` because you did not actually need it.
- Cleaned up your `print` because it was hard to read. You could also try `printf`
- You have two files named dir (`%dir` and `$dir`) which I find confusing in this case so I renamed `%dir` to `%dirs`.

CODE:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %dirs;

# Part 1 - Input
my $filename_input = "file_name.txt";
open(my $IN,'<',$filename_input) or die "Unable to open [$filename_input] for reading - $!";
while(<$IN>) {
    my ($prot, $dir) = split;
    push @{$dirs{$prot}}, $dir;
}
close $IN;

# Part 2 - Output
my $filename_results = "results_file.txt";
open(my $RESULTS,'<',$filename_results) or die "Unable to open [$filename_results] for reading - $!";
while(<$RESULTS>) {
    chomp;
    my $prot = (split)[1];
    foreach (values %dirs) {
        print "$prot\t@{$dirs{$prot}}\n"; # Or try: printf "%s\t%s\n",$prot,"@{$dirs{$prot}}";
    }
}
close $RESULTS;
```

file_name.txt

```
BC_123456     dir_6789
BC_456789     dir_3456
BC_234689     dir_1298
BC_123456     dir_3987
BC_876432     dir_7642
```

results_file.txt

```
don'tcare BC_123456
don'tcare BC_234689
```